# Как получить элемент документа html внутри другого документа html Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python

Возможно ли это? Например, нужно кликнуть на один из элементов **div**. Внутренний документ вложен в **iframe**.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    ....
     <head>
      ....
       <body>
        ....
         <iframe src = '...'>

         #document
           <!doctype html>
             <div class = ''></div>
             <div class = ''></div>
             <div class = ''></div>
           </html>

         </iframe>
         ....
       </body>
```

Пробовал этот код, но он не работает.

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"));
element = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("div")
print (element)
>> []
```

Comment: Кликнуть внутри iframe или о чём речь?

Comment: @andreymal да, Вы правы. Отредактировал вопрос. Нужно кликнуть внутрь iframe.

Comment: Добавил информацию. Но данный код не работает. Возвращает пустой массив.